# App not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have made my first hello world program in android studio and when I launched  for the first time (without any images), it was working . But when I put a photo using imageview then when I created the apk it doesn't run saying that the app has stopped working.
following is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.himan.helloworld1.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello Himan"
/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="From Rakesh"
    />
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/happy_birthday"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Close your `</RelativeLayout>` tag at end and post your java code.

Comment: I don't see any app here. Add your code and your error message.

Comment: Add Activitiy's code to see what are you doing with this ImageView.

Comment: try using height width to 50 dp once >

Answer (score 0):

You can see Video tutorial here

Android Hello World Example
Android Tutorial For Beginners - https://youtu.be/-Cfl6BdLT5K